# java : Create multiple threads with different names (without using for loop)

Tags: java, multithreading

I am working on a project where I have to create on or more new threads when a particular condition is satisfied. Basically I am stuck in creating new threads with different names every time as I am not aware how many threads would be generated in tun time.

Example : Thread t1= new thread();
Thread t2= new thread(); and so on..
 Here I am not aware of whether I would be requiring till t10 or t99.

Comment: You mean you need to be able to track them later on by ID?

Comment: Are the IDs always consecutive numbers?

Comment: yes it would be consecutive

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked for no loop, but would this get what you need?

```
int numberOfThreads = //whatever;
 ArrayList<Thread> threadList = new ArrayList<>();
 for(int i = 0; i<numberOfThreads; i++)
 {
    Thread t = new Thread();
    threadList.add(t);
}
```

You can call the threads by index instead of name, threadList.get(number);

Comment: NOpe... I dont know how many threads would be initiated at run time.

Comment: @MohdAminSayyed but your program will be able to track it, no?

Comment: @MohdAminSayyed: Use whatever loop you want; this is how you should keep track of the threads.

Comment: Sure, I can use loop in tracking of threads, But creating multiple threads without using loop is my actual problem.. I mean initialising multiple thread and running them.

Comment: How do you determine if you need more threads? What condition are you checking for?

Answer (score 1):

First things first:

There are no dynamical variables in java. You've to declare them in the sourcecode.

To archieve your identifier problem you could use a `HashMap`:

```
Map<String, Thread> hm = new HashMap<String, Thread>();
```

And a method that adds threads to it:

```
public void addThreadToMap(Thread t) {
    hm.put("t" + hm.size().toString(), t);       //This will add the thread with the key [t0 .... tn]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just create an ArrayList and add a new one each time.